# Error when setting up the application in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.8

I am trying to composer update the command on my existing laravel5.8 project. For that I run the below command :
"**composer update**".

Laravel get updated without any fail and after that I tried to clear the config and cache..but when I tried to do so I am getting the below error for every action

In Container.php line 788:

**Class seed.handler does not exist**

When I run the website locally , I get 500 error and apache logs say :
**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist in /var/www/html/pombackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:788**

I searched everywhere but did not get the fix for this. Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: to which version of laravel are you migrating?

Comment: Please share more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `composer dump-autoload` to fix this kind of issue.

Make sure your .env file is properly written, no hidden space in front. Also make sure APP_KEY is generated. `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I am getting error "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class translator does not exist in /var/www/html/pombackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php"

Comment: @ssnegi have you run ```composer install``` yet?

Comment: @ssnegi did you changed anything inside config folder? Usually this issue related to syntax error inside a config file.

Comment: Thanks Adaln , the issue is fixed . there was issue in the configuration

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `composer.json` file:

```
 "config": {

    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/installers": true,
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
        "roots/wordpress-core-installer": true
    }
},
```

Hope so it will work.